# String matching in insert trigger - how to use in conditionals to return NULL?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, string-matching, postgresql-8.4

In PostgreSQL 8.4.13 database with UTF8 encoding I keep a (non-English) dictionary in this table:

```
create table good_words (
        word varchar(64) primary key
);
```

And a list of wrong (but often suggested or mistyped) words in:

```
create table bad_words (
        word varchar(64) primary key
);
```

For the former table I have an [BEFORE INSERT trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) which I am trying to extend:

```
create or replace function keep_clean() returns trigger as $body$
        begin
                new.word := upper(new.word);

                perform true
                        from bad_words
                        where word = new.word;

                if found then
                        return null;
                end if;

                -- forbid words with [XYZ] at beginning and Z at the end
                -- forbid words with LLL unless it is KLLL or MLLL

                return new;
        end;
$body$ language plpgsql;

create trigger count_letters
        BEFORE INSERT on good_words
        for each row execute procedure keep_clean();
```

**My problem is:** I am trying to add 3 rules (returning `NULL`) to my trigger:

1. Words starting with X, Y or Z letter are forbidden
2. Words ending with Z letter are forbidden
3. Words with 3 same letters in a row are very rare and are only allowed if they are `like '%KLLL%' or like '%MLLL%'`

As Perl programmer I know regexes well, but my problem is the Pl/PgSQL part - how to perform the regex matching in that language, do I always have to use `SELECT INTO` or `PERFORM`? Or can I use `:=` operator here or maybe even perform a string matching inside the `IF` statement?

**UPDATE:**

After Craig's explanation (thank you!) I have prepared [the following SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/0e834), but it still has 2 problems:

```
create table good_words (
        word varchar(64) primary key
);

create or replace function keep_clean() returns trigger as $body$
        begin
                new.word := upper(new.word);

                /* next line does not compile? */
                IF new.word !~ '^[\x0410-\x042F]{2,}$' THEN
                    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Not an uppercased Russian word in UTF8';
                END IF;

                IF new.word ~ '^[ЪЫЬ]' OR new.word ~ 'Ъ$' THEN
                    return NULL;
                END IF;

                /* does not return NULL for 'ошибббка'? */
                IF new.word ~ '(.)\1\1' AND new.word NOT LIKE '%ШЕЕЕ%' AND new.word NOT LIKE '%ЗМЕЕЕ%' THEN
                    return NULL;
                END IF;

                return new;
        end;
$body$ language plpgsql;
```

It shouldn't take the 1st two words in UTF8 encoding here, but it does:

```
insert into good_words (word)
  values
    ('abcde'),          /* bad word: non-russian */
    ('ошибббка'),       /* bad word: 3 letters in a row */
    ('длинношеее'),
    ('проверка')
;

select * from good_words;
```

**UPDATE 2:** Trigger works now, thank you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/98403/1

Comment: Why don't you create a check constraint for that?

Comment: I feed my `good_words` table repeatedly with new words to extend the dictionary and would like bad words just fail silently - which wouldn't be the case with check constraints. And also I do more stuff in my INSERT trigger: I count letter frequencies and store in an ARRAY columnt (omitted in my question) there for my word game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PostgreSQL's `~` operator or the `regexp_matches` function. See [pattern matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) in the documentation.

Simple PL/PgSQL example:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
  IF 'XABCK' ~ '^[XY]' THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Disallowed character';
  END IF;
END;
$$;
```

As you can see, `IF` can take expressions. These expressions may be of arbitrary complexity and may include subqueries, `CASE`, pretty much anything legal in SQL.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please take a look at the 2 problems in my SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/0e834 ? I have updated my question too

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Upgrade PostgreSQL; I'm pretty sure utf-8 support in regex was rather lacking in 8.4. Your "russian word" regexp compiles and works fine for me on 9.2.